# Why arent the USB ports working on my install of centOS 5.10?

Tags: centos, usb

I have installed centOS 5.10 on a recently purchased desktop computer. The brand is SION, it is a clone.

Motherboard: GIGABYTE J1800 (2.41 GHz)

When I boot up the machine, this error keeps coming up:

```
usb 1.1: device not accepting address 2, error -110 linux
```

When the system finishes loading, none of my USB ports work.

I tried installing different versions of centOS, but the result is always the same (the error, then no usb functionality).

Comment: You should identify the hardware (laptop or motherboard model), this appears to be a driver issue.

Comment: thanks for the tip, @goldilocks. Ive just added this info, please take a look

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the `usb-storage.ko` driver using:

```
# modprobe usb-storage
```

Comment: thank you! should I do this from the / ? first cd / and then run the command?

Comment: Yes, you can execute the command from /

Comment: Thanks Karthik. I tried it, the command runs, but it doesn't work :(. Any other suggestions?